# Как вызвать метод внутри метода?

Tags: c#, классы, методы

Как обратиться отдельно к методу CheckQMin(), игнорируя CheckQMax()?

```
public class CheckSum
    {
        public void CS(int amount)
        {
            void CheckQMin()
            {
            
            }

            void CheckQMax()
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Если никак, то подскажите: как переменную amount распространить на весь класс

Comment: 1 - никак. 2 - сохраните ее в переменные класса.

Comment: Ну как - просто взять и обратиться. В чём вопрос то? Это обычный метод, чтобы он выполнился, к нему нужно обратиться. А второй метод не вызывайте, он и не выполнится. Просто это локально описанные методы, видные только внутри метода `CS`. Но вызываются они как любые другие методы - непосредственным обращением (вызовом). В общем, оба вопроса не очень понятны, приведите какой-то код, который вы планируете вокруг этой штуки использовать, а то непонятно что вы хотите. Или вы хотите снаружи к этим методам обращаться? Снаружи нельзя, да.

Comment: Покажите, как именно вы хотите их вызывать (кодом, а не словами!) и тогда вам подскажут, что куда перенести.

Answer (score 1):

Без изменения кода метода CheckSum.CS() обратиться напрямую к методу CheckQMin() не получится, потому что он является локальным для метода CS() и не доступен извне.

Однако, вы можете вынести метод CheckQMin() из метода CS() в сам класс CheckSum, сделав его публичным методом, и обращаться к нему отдельно.